# How to generate a time series column from today to the next 600 days in pandas?

Tags: pandas, time-series

How to generate a time series column from today to the next 600 days in pandas?

I'm a new pandas learner. I can generate a new column as follows:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2011-8-23', freq='D')
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-01', '2010-01-02', '2010-01-03', '2010-01-04',
               '2010-01-05', '2010-01-06', '2010-01-07', '2010-01-08',
               '2010-01-09', '2010-01-10',
               ...
               '2011-08-14', '2011-08-15', '2011-08-16', '2011-08-17',
               '2011-08-18', '2011-08-19', '2011-08-20', '2011-08-21',
               '2011-08-22', '2011-08-23'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=600, freq='D')
```

My question is: what should we do if we do only know the starting date, and the time period 600 days? **we don't know the ending date**. How to modify the code?

And another follow up questions, how to set the starting date to current or yesterday's date?

Comment: You could try adding 600 days to it using the datetime module

Comment: kind of '2011-8-23' + 600? can you explain it further, because I'm not good at time series module. Thank you mmenschig.

Comment: Haven Shi - yes kind of, please check my answer from below

Comment: Thank you mmenschig! I import datetime and solve it.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved the issue for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, import core package datetime

```
import datetime
```

Then you can instantiate a datetime object and add 600 days using the `timedelta()` method

```
start_date = "2010-01-01"
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")

end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=600)
```

To now get the string back, we can use `strftime()` like:

```
end_date = end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
> '2011-08-24'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the period to 600, you should get your out put

```
pd.date_range(start='2010-01-01', periods=5, freq='D')
Out[335]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-01', '2010-01-02', '2010-01-03', '2010-01-04',
               '2010-01-05'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

For get today'date

```
pd.to_datetime('today')

Out[338]: Timestamp('2017-09-29 00:00:00')
```